# jQuery closest() not working for me (or i'm not working for it)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given this jQuery:

```
$('div.MvcFieldWrapper :input').focus(function() {
      $(this).closest('label.MvcDynamicFieldError').fadeOut();
});
```

And given this HTML:

```
<div class="MvcFieldWrapper">
    <label class="MvcDynamicFieldPrompt">Enter your email address:</label>
    <label class="MvcDynamicFieldError">Required</label>
    <input type="text" value="" />
</div>
```

Why is the label not fading out when I focus on the input? I know for sure that the focus event is happening.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Closest looks through the "parents" not siblings. What you want is [`prevAll`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/):

```
$('div.MvcFieldWrapper :input').focus(function() {
      $(this).prevAll('label.MvcDynamicFieldError').fadeOut();
});
```

`closest` actually means "find the closest ancestor that matches the selector, including the already selected element if it meets the requirements."

Comment: @Jonathan I knew you were on, so I had to type super fast and post often :)