# Jquery wont hide label on keypress

Tags: jquery

I have the code live [here(JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/buyC9/148/):

Jquery does not hide the label on keypress.

JQUERY:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input').keypress(function(){
$(this).closest('label').hide();
});
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="login">
<h2 style="font-size:18px;">Login</h2>

<form method="post" id="user_new" class="user_new" action="/users/sign_in" accept-charset="UTF-8"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input type="hidden" value="✓" name="utf8"><input type="hidden" value="CFIZzyFucEG03h33m6dzX9DNy/Ux11yjShcT2xZnZRs=" name="authenticity_token"></div>
  <p style="position: relative; float: left; margin-bottom: 0px;"><label style="position:absolute;margin:0px;top:10px;left:20px;color:#CCCCCC;" for="user_email">Email</label>
  <input type="email" value="" size="30" name="user[email]" id="user_email">
  </p>

  <p style="position: relative; float: left; margin-top: 5px;"><label style="position:absolute;margin:0px;top:10px;left:20px;color:#CCCCCC;" for="user_kodeord">Kodeord</label>
  <input type="password" size="30" name="user[password]" id="user_password">
  </p>

    <p><input type="hidden" value="0" name="user[remember_me]"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="user[remember_me]" id="user_remember_me"> <label for="user_Husk_mig">Husk mig</label></p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Login" name="commit" id="user_submit"></p>
<div style="    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 400px;margin-left: -20px;">
  <a href="/users/sign_up">Sign up</a><br>

  <a href="/users/password/new">Forgot your password?</a><br>



</div>
</form></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what part of your HTML you're referring to, but to select `<label>` elements next to your input, you need to use [`$.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) for immediately previous elements and [`$.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) for elements immediately after your input.

`$.closest()` selects the closes *parent* of the element, not the "physically" closest element in the DOM, which is why your `<label>` isn't being hidden; it's not selected.

Answer (score 0):

The closest method from jQuery is searching for the selector in the parents of the object. For searching for the closest sibling you should take a look at prevAll/nextAll

See 
[jQuery closest() not working for me (or i'm not working for it)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170799/jquery-closest-not-working-for-me-or-im-not-working-for-it)

Or the jQuery API documentation
prevAll - http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/
nextAll - http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/
and
closest - http://api.jquery.com/closest/